# appium+protractor multiCapabilities for linux platform is possible?

Tags: protractor, appium

Their are 2 users having different roles:

1. Doctor [login from pc web browser]
2. Patient [login from android app]

My protractor config file

```
multiCapabilities:[{
    browserName: 'android',
    platformName: 'android',
    platformVersion: '6.0',
    deviceName: 'android',
    autoWebview: true,
    app: '/home/myPc/e2e/build/android/patient.apk',
    autoGrantPermissions: 'true',
    framework: 'jasmine'
},{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    platformName:'linux',
}],
```

when i run test it througs error: Could not find a driver for platformName 'linux'

Comment: Modify `platformName:'linux'` to `platform:'LINUX'` and check once!

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj i have set your solution then it's gives another error: You must include a platformName capability